# Windows Authentication PopUp

Tags: sharepoint-server

I've setup SharePoint 2019 and I'm having an issue windows authentication where a login box is shown to the site.  I've read tons of doc and here is what I have done:

Web Application port: 443
Full Read for accounts:

```
NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL_SERVICE,  
<Share Point User>, 
All Users (windows)
```

Under the Site.  In Site Permissions I added:

```
Site Visitors - Read
```

Advanced Permission Settings:

```
Everyone - Domain Group - Read
SharePoint Group - Read
```

but every time a user goes to the site page it asks for authentication.  Any ideas on what I'm missing.  Its setup to use AD authentication.
For example, if I set up a domain user as a Farm Administrator and have them go to the central admin page:    http://someserver:11667 it works with the page showing but on the site page it prompts for a login still.

I've seen articles about adding the site to your local browser as trusted sites.  But since we using Windows 10 client and Window 2016 Server with SharePoint 2019, I would have thought it would work.  I'm testing on Edge, Chrome and Firefox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edge and Firefox, this is expected. Add the site to the Trusted Sites list in IE and then test with Chrome.

Comment: So there is no way to have auto detect without making client-side changes?

Comment: Typically IE (thus Chrome) will treat URLs without dots as they're in the Intranet Zone, but all of that depends on your configuration. Edge does not have a concept of Zones and Firefox has some manual changes you can make in about:config (there are some FF GPOs now, as well, that can handle this).

Comment: Trevor Thank you for the the quick and helpfull response

Answer (score 0):

To handle the basic authentication popup, we can pass the username and password along with the web page's URL. When the login pop-up is prompted, we enter the username as “admin” and the password as “admin” and then log in. Thus, the user would be successfully logged into the website.